# Gazebo fails to load

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get ROS and Care-O-Bot installed and running for some time now.  I can never get Gazebo to initialize properly.   I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, and Fuerte

I start with the instructions here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Care-O-bot/fuerte

Then these:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_bringup_sim

I can get through all of the ROS tutorials, so I believe that everything has been done correctly with respect to ROS, but when I run cob_bringup_sim Gazebo fails with the following error:

**Error [Plugin.hh:100] Failed to load plugin -1: -1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Warning [parser.cc:332] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element

Warning [parser.cc:243] parser for sdf version 1.0 failed, trying to parse as old deprecated format

Segmentation fault**

For reference, here is the Gazebo cmd that cob_bringup_sim generates, running this line solo creates the same error:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -s -1 /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/cob_environments/cob_gazebo_worlds/common/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/nathan/.ros/log/58188a6e-bee5-11e1-bd07-f46d0412dc71/gazebo-2.log

No log file is generated, and I can only assume that Gazebo never even attempts to load.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37220/gazebo-fails-to-load/) by [natbur](https://answers.ros.org/users/2709/natbur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-10**:
what file is missing ?? i think there should be any .so file or so by:
Error [Plugin.hh:100] Failed to load plugin -1: -1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to stem from the combination of Fuerte and COB.  As soon as I rolled back to Electric, everything started working.  Not sure if something has changed in the format of the simulation files for Fuerte that makes the current COB code not work, but for now I'm just sticking to Electric.

---

Originally posted by [natbur](https://answers.ros.org/users/2709/natbur/) with karma: 26 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0